# How to add NSTextTable editing features in NSTextView menu?

Tags: swift, nstextview, nstexttab

Good day,

I'll like to know how to add NSTextTable editing features in NSTextView menu such as adding row above and below, deleting the column and removing the table, I know how to call the table panel for NSTextView. I would like to know if apple already provides functionality for this or if I would need to program it from scratch.

if apple doesn't provide the functionality. I would like to know how to know when an NSTextTable is being edited and what cell the cursor is currently on.

I would appreciate if someone takes their time to help me with this.

Thank you